# Xml serialization - Change the serialization type of xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a struct like this:

```
public struct Vehicles
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public struct Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<Tire> Tires { get; set; }
}

public struct Tire
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int UniqueCount { get; set; }
    public List<Dimension> Dimensions { get; set; }
}

public struct Dimension
{
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public int AlternateSize { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize "Vehicles" it is like:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema">
  <Vehicles>
    <Name>SuperVehicles</Name>
    <Cars>
      <Car>
        <Name>BMW</Name>
        <Count>29</Count>
        <Tires>
          <Tire>
            <Name>DMZ</Name>
            <Count>26</Count>
            <UniqueCount>24</UniqueCount>
            <Dimensions>
              <Dimension>
                <Size>70x570</Size>
                <AlternateSize>70x580</AlternateSize>
              </Dimension>
              <Dimension>
                <Size>60x570</Size>
                <AlternateSize>60x580</AlternateSize>
              </Dimension>
              <Dimension>
                <Size>50x570</Size>
                <AlternateSize>50x580</AlternateSize>
              </Dimension>
            </Dimensions>
          </Tire>
        </Tires>
      </Car>
    </Cars>
  </Vehicles>
</root>
```

Now the problem is, I want to serialize it like this:

```
<root>
  <vehicles vehicleName="superVehicles" vehicleCount="50" carName="BMW"
      carCount="25" tireBrand="kamu" tireCount="15" tireUniqueCount="15"
      dimensionSize="70x570" dimensionAlternateSize="70x580" />
  <vehicles vehicleName="superVehicles" vehicleCount="35" carName="MERCEDES"
      carCount="22" tireBrand="kamu" tireCount="12" tireUniqueCount="12"
      dimensionSize="60x570" dimensionAlternateSize="60x580" />
  <vehicles vehicleName="superVehicles" vehicleCount="35" carName="PORSCHE"
      carCount="22" tireBrand="kamu" tireCount="12" tireUniqueCount="12"
      dimensionSize="60x570" dimensionAlternateSize="60x580" />
</root>
```

Do I have to change the structure and avoid the groupings or is there any way to create a schema for xml serialization to gather this result.

Summary:
I get all the child items in a new tag when I serialize the root struct to xml but I need to take them as properties of an instance that create only the count of root (Vehicles in this situation) element of rows to xml.

Comment: Sorry didn't see you were editing it.  Feel free to roll back if I screwed it up :)

Comment: @Merlyn nope! I screwed it up. Couldn't fix to show xml code block right. Please help me and it would be nice to tell me how to do that(:

Comment: I had the XML showing in my edit...

Comment: Indent 4 spaces and the JS magically syntax hilights.  It doesn't need any hint for what code type it is (and I'm not sure if it even has a syntax to provide one).  I rolled back to my edit since it has that right.  Roll back to Marc's if you want the indenting I did removed, but the syntax hilighting (first 4 spaces indent) still correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do manual serialization.

Here is how you can implement this using System.Xml.Linq :

```
var xmlElementsVehicles  = new[]{
                                  new XElement("vehicles ", new object[]
                                  {
                                   new XElement("vehicleName", "superVehicles"),
                                   new XElement("vehicleCount", 35),
                                   new XElement("carName", "PORSCHE"),
                                   new XElement("carCount", 2)
                                  }),
                                  new XElement("vehicles ", new object[]
                                  {
                                   new XElement("vehicleName", "superVehicles"),
                                   new XElement("vehicleCount", 35),
                                   new XElement("carName", "PORSCHE"),
                                   new XElement("carCount", 2)
                                  })
                                };
var root = new XElement("root", xmlElementsVehicles );
var myXml = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), root);
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
{
  myXml.Save(xmlWriter);
}
```

Comment: oh, thanks for that. I guess there's no auto-config for that, like I could define a schema and it uses that, right?

Comment: @Beytan: No, nothing automatic about it.  There is [an interface you can implement on your data type(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) to tell the Xml serializer to use this implementation, though.

Answer (score 1):

To use XmlSerializer the model must *roughly* be the same as the layout; a few things can change (names, etc). However, your model is *nothing like* the XML. Three options, then:

- create a second DTO model that looks like the XML (you can use xsd.exe on the sample XML to automate this), and use XmlSerializer
- don't use XmlSerializer, but build the XML somehow else (XmlDocument or XDocument would be the obvious two, or XmlWriter if the size is very large)
- use something like xslt to reshape the XML after writing

There is nothing "easy" can be done to make XmlSerializer write that model into your desired XML.

Comment: I guess xslt is the right answer to this, but it would be nice to provide an example to be brief.

Comment: to the xslt one. The first one is not easy for me to do. the second one is a little manual I guess, no sure though. the 3rd one is a bit automated I guess, I understood it like: create this xml and provide a xslt to manipulate it, right?

Comment: +1; @Beytan: Since there's nothing easy, I recommend double checking the requirement to use an existing XML format.  If there isn't a real need for it, then it is probably easier to live with the Xml your code is already producing.  Less to write and maintain that way.  You could also look into using Xml serialization attributes.  They might get you half way to what you want (e.g. [using attributes instead of elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx)).

Comment: @Beytan there are lots of xslt walk-thrus available - are you familiar with xslt?

Comment: @Marc some from sharepoint. I'll look it up and try that way, thanks.

Comment: @Merlyn I'll check my structure first. I guess there's something wrong with it(: thanks guys